# 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'mean'

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

I have this Python code which calculates the correlation between two arrays. But when I try to execute this code, I find this error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'mean'.

How can i solve this problem?

```
import numpy as np
def Correlation_f(X,Y):
if len(X)== len(Y):
    Sum_xy = (sum((X - X.mean()) * (Y - Y.mean())))/len(X)
    Sum_x_squared = (sum((X - X.mean()) ** 2))/len(X)
    Sum_y_squared = (sum((Y - Y.mean()) ** 2))/len(Y)
    corre = Sum_xy / np.sqrt(Sum_x_squared * Sum_y_squared)
    return corre
```

Comment: Show the full error message.  All you are showing is one function.  How are we supposed to help? Why do you use lists instead of arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how you are running you code, but one issue could be that you are passing in a python list as apposed to a np array. To fix this you should convert the lists to a NumPy array using np.array(list_name)

The other reason you might have an issue is that to use np's mean function you must use the syntax np.mean(arr) not arr.mean(). You can find more spesific info here: https://sparkbyexamples.com/numpy/numpy-array-mean-function/